# Empty parameter in meta_value

Tags: php, wordpress, alert

I have a option, where the user can add alert message, and when the page is Loaded, it should be displayed. The problem is that the alert is displayed, but withoud the message, that the user writes and im not sure why.

```
if( !empty( $postdata ) ) {
                foreach( $postdata as $dx_section ) {
                    var_dump( $dx_section );
                    foreach ( $dx_section->column_array as $value ) {
                        if ( $value->column_view == 'alert' && $value->column_indx == $id ) {
                            $column_data  = isset( $value->column_data ) ? $value->column_data : "";
                            $column_alert = isset( $value->column_alert ) ? $value->column_alert : "";

                            if ( $column_alert == 'On Page Load' ) {
                                if (isset( $column_data )) {
                                    echo '<script>alert( "' . $column_data . '" )</script>';
                                }
                            } else if ( isset( $value->column_alert_ids ) ) {
                                $id_array = explode( " ", $value->column_alert_ids );
                                echo '<script>';
                                foreach ( $id_array as $key ) {
                                    echo 'jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                                            $(document).find("#' . $key . '").click(function() {
                                                alert("' . $column_data . '");
                                            } );
                                    } );';
                                }
                                echo '</script>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```

The column_data is empty, it should be the message.
Here is the dumped $dx_section variable

```
object(stdClass)[258]
  public 'section_order' => int 1
  public 'section_name' => string 'First Section Name' (length=18)
  public 'section_classes' => string 'Section Classes' (length=15)
  public 'section_margin' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'section_padding' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'column_array' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[257]
          public 'row_class' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'column_name' => string 'Alert Window 1' (length=14)
          public 'column_size' => string '12' (length=2)
          public 'col_class' => string 'Column Classes' (length=14)
          public 'column_view' => string 'alert' (length=5)
          public 'column_indx' => int 1
          public 'column_alert' => string 'On Page Load' (length=12)
          public 'column_alert_ids' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'column_data' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'extension_data' => 
            object(stdClass)[595]
              ...
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[596]
          public 'row_class' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'column_name' => string 'Custom Text' (length=11)
          public 'column_size' => string '12' (length=2)
          public 'col_class' => string 'Column Classes' (length=14)
          public 'column_view' => string 'custom_text' (length=11)
          public 'column_indx' => int 2
          public 'column_class' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'column_padding' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'column_padding_type' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'column_background' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'column_boder' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'column_data' => string '<p><strong>Custom data...</strong></p>
' (length=39)
          public 'extension_data' => 
            object(stdClass)[594]
              ...
```

Comment: What if you use `if (isset( $column_data ) && $column_data) {`?

Comment: Can you write it as answer with the code, because i cannot orient

Comment: I think you are getting blank in `$column_data`, try to use `var_dump` it will definitely give you some clue to solve this issue.

Comment: It outputs an empty string

Comment: Clearly, you need to work on statement `var_dump( $dx_section );`.

Comment: I've editeed the question

Comment: @RohanKumar i the problem in the column_alert_ids which is empty but i can't understand why